# use {block:More} in custom tumblr theme

Tags: html, tumblr

I am making a custom tumblr theme. i want to use substr in my theme and a read more link, but i am not able to do it. How to cut text in custom tumblr theme, the text is coming through {caption}.

Answer (score 2):

You should use JS for it, tumblr allows all kinds of (jQuery) JS tricks to "re-render" your content after the page is loaded (dom ready). Give the concerning HTML element an id or class to refer to it by JS.

So, your post title "use {block:More} in custom tumblr theme" is confusing. Tumblrs block:More construct is not for your purpose, but "Rendered on index pages for posts with Read More breaks" as http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes states.